# What are the odds based on time?

Tags: random-variables, time-series

I need to know the odds in order to determine if this method of generating a random number will be effective.

The variables:
A counter based on milliseconds to the 7th digit.
    This is a counter that iterates every millisecond. (0-9999999)
This counter will reset when it reaches 9999999.

Every year 30,000 numbers will be pulled from this set of numbers.
What are the chances one of these numbers will repeat?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  What are your thought and efforts on this question ?

Comment: The basic odds would be calculated as 30,000/9,999,999 = 0.003 or 0.3% chance of a duplicate number.  That's with a static range of numbers 1to 9999999.  I'm not sure how counter being based on time factors into it.  I'm thinking it would decrease the odds of a duplicate.

Comment: Are you asking what are the chances that one of the 30,000 numbers from year 2 will be a duplicate of one of the 30,000 numbers from year 1?

Comment: What are the chances one of the 30,000 numbers randomly pulled will be a duplicate within the same year.  After a number has been active for one year it can be used again without being considered a duplicate. I am focused on the odds for just the first year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially the Birthday Problem, on a planet where the year has $10^8$ days and we have 30,000 people in the room. We want to know the probability that at least two people will have the same birthday. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

The exact solution would be a computational nightmare due to the size of the numbers involved, but we can employ what the Wikipedia page calls the Poisson approximation.  There are $\binom{30,000}{2}$ pairs of people, and for any pair, the probability that the two people have the same birthday is $10^{-8}$.  So the expected number of matches is
$$\lambda = \binom{30,000}{2} \cdot 10^{-8} \approx 4.50$$
It seems reasonable to assume that the number of matches, say $X$, is approximately distributed as a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$; so the probability that there is at least one match is approximately
$$\Pr(X > 0) = 1-e^{-\lambda} \approx 0.9889$$